# Make a custom field image be used as featured image

Tags: php, wordpress

My client old theme wasn't using the featured image to be displayed on the top of the page. Instead, they are using a custom field that works the same way as a featured image.

The problem is that they needed to add a plugin that makes a grid and its not showing the image of each post because the featured image field is empty.

There are over 600 posts and manually filling the featured images is too much time.

Is there a way to start using the custom field as technically the featured image so that it shows where an ever a featured image would show?

That's the PHP that calls the image on the single post page:

```
                        <?php if (!empty($post->news_image)): ?>
                            <img class="news-image" src="<?php

                            echo $post->news_image;

                            ?>" alt="News Thumb" />
                        <?php endif ?>

Thats the code at the beguinign of the single post php file:

    $theme_url = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/';
$base_url = get_bloginfo('url').'/';
$current_lang = pll_current_language();
$current_URI = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];


// get related news
$news_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'category__not_in' => pll_get_term(171),
    'exclude' => $post->ID,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'news_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);
$other_news = get_posts($news_args);


// find Prev & Next news
$news_args["posts_per_page"] = -1;
unset($news_args["exclude"]);

$all_news = get_posts($news_args);

foreach ($all_news as $k => $item) {
    if ($item->ID == $post->ID) {
        $prev_page = isset($all_news[$k-1]) ? $all_news[$k-1] : null;
        $next_page = isset($all_news[$k+1]) ? $all_news[$k+1] : null;
    }
}

$closebuttonlink = $base_url;

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'investors/news') !== false) {
    $closebuttonlink = $base_url."investors/news/";
}
else if (preg_match('/\/investors/', wp_get_referer())) {
        $closebuttonlink = $base_url."investors/";
}
else
{
        $closebuttonlink = $base_url;
}



function get_ir_news_permalink($post_object)
{
    $base_url = get_bloginfo('url').'/';
    return $base_url.'investors/news_view/'.$post_object->post_name;
}
if(in_category(141) && preg_match('/media\/news_view/', $current_URI)) {
    wp_redirect(get_ir_news_permalink($post));
}
if(in_category(272) && preg_match('/media\/news_view/', $current_URI)) {
    wp_redirect(get_ir_news_permalink($post));
}


set_query_var( 'section', 2 );

set_query_var( 'newsdetails', 1 );
// select Investor section menu

// load header
get_header();
```

Comment: Please can you post the wordpress loop for $post or the code in your single post page.

Comment: I just edited the post

Comment: You have 2 option.

1) you will replace your code custom field (image) instead of the featured image code
2) Create SQL query to copy the custom filed path to the featured image.
But it totally depends on the field type.

Comment: Can you help me go through option 1? @Jagirbahesh

Comment: Please see my answer as below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are three ways to get image field as below.

**1. Return value = image object** (screen-shot:https://screencast.com/t/gTdgeU0Y)

Note: please add your id instead of 'image'

```
<?php 
    $image = get_field('image');
    if( !empty($image) ):
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

**2. Return value = Image Url**

```
<?php if( get_field('image') ): ?>
     <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

**3. Return value = Image ID**

```
<?php 
$image = get_field('image');
$size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

if( $image )
{
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
}
?>
```

Please place the above code where you want to get an image. Hope this will work for you :)

Comment: Oh I guess what I need is the MySQL solution because the plugin is only taking featrued images

Comment: Maybe a loop in the functions.php file where each posts gets a featured image from either one of the custom fields