# Assign featured image using MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My client has a custom made theme that uses custom fields instead of featured images.

I added some new plugins and I need to start using featured image instead.

So instead of updating every single post, I thought there's a way to do it using MySQL.

I want to create a MySQL query that transfers all the custom fields values to the featured image.

The theme uses 2 custom fields:

1. For single image posts:

   `$post->news_image`
2. For Gallery: // it takes the first image of the gallery

   ```
                   <?php if( has_shortcode($pin->post_content, 'gallery' ) ): ?>

                       <?php $gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $pin ); ?> 
                       <?php $mythumbs = $gallery[0]; ?>

                   <?php endif ?>
   ```

Should I create a new php file with MySQL in it? and what should it contain?

Comment: Hi @Robin it doesn't help if you are creating multiple questions with different info. Your other question was answered, please provide feedback on it and close this question as it's related to the other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332274/make-a-custom-field-image-be-used-as-featured-image

Comment: I'm trying to see the multiple ways I can handle the problem I'm facing the problem is the same but the first question was a PHP workaround and this is a MySQL overwrite